# Is there a way to store an instance method inside a variable without running that function first? In Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, instance

I am trying to store an instance method as a variable so I can pass it into a way to store logic on a menu I am building.

For example, I want my `our_startup.prompt` method to be stored in my `start_game_ui.logic` array. I am trying to do this using a `start_game_ui.set_logic` function which shovels arguments into the logic array. I would like to shovel 6 methods into the logic array so that when I run my final function to puts and receive input 1 - 6. If the user chooses `1` it should run the function in the first element of the array.

```
our_startup = Startup.new("No Name")

## START GAME UI ##
start_game_ui = UI.new("start_game_ui")
start_game_ui.menu_items = ["[1] - Yes", "[2] - Generate Another"]

##set up logic##
method1_test = our_startup.set_name("test")
rerun = start_game_ui.prompt
start_game_ui.set_logic(method1_test, rerun)
```

When I run this, my `start_game_ui.prompt` method will run. I want to store the `start_game_ui.prompt` method in that variable `rerun` without having the method run.

Once I run my final method and choose `1` it should return `"test"`. However when I run this it runs `start_game_ui.prompt` and I don't want it to.

I hope you can understand what I mean. I have 2 classes `UI` and `Startup` if you couldn't already tell.

PLEASE DO NOT TELL ME I CAN DO `method(:something)` this does not help as it is an instance method being called by another instance. Unless you can tell me how to get that symbol to correspond with the correct method inside the instance. I've tried `method(our_startup.prompt)` and it does not work.

Comment: This can be trivially solved using `Object#method`, which is the correct approach. The fact you exclude its usage makes this question very hard to answer.

Comment: Is [instance_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_method) any help?

Comment: "I've tried method(our_startup.prompt) and it does not work." - of course not. Should've been `our_startup.method(:prompt)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> PLEASE DO NOT TELL ME I CAN DO `method(:something)` this does not help as it is an instance method being called by another instance.

I would really like to not tell you that, but unfortunately, that *is* the correct answer:

```
rerun = start_game_ui.method(:prompt)
# Then, later when you need to call it:
result = rerun.()
```

*Not* using [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method), as you require in your question, leads to significant added complexity, e.g. by passing around the receiver and the name of the method separately:

```
rerun_receiver_and_message = [start_game_ui, :prompt]
# Then, later when you need to call it:
result = rerun_receiver_and_message.first.public_send(rerun_receiver_and_message.last)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I did not know that I could put the instance in front of .method. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is nothing different from what is in your question: you call `method` on `self`, therefore, you get a method bound to `self`. I call `method` on `start_game_ui`, therefore, I get a method bound to `start_game_ui`. It is *exactly the same thing*. Whatever object you call `method` on, the returned `Method` will be bound to that object. This is actually the very first code example in [the documentation of `Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method).

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to get the instance method from inside the instance of your object, then you can use this: `our_startup.method(:prompt)`

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm new to contributing here, so possibly didn't phrase my input right. I still think my answer possibly solves the stated question, so I've rephrased it. Hope that helps :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can store in variables and pass as arguments are objects.

Procs and Lambdas are objects, so you should be able to do something like

```
rerun = -> {start_game_ui.prompt}
start_game_ui.set_logic(method1_test, rerun)
```

`rerun` is storing the call to the method, not the results of the method

At the point where you need to execute the method, you would do

```
rerun.call
```

Note that Procs and Lambdas can also specify arguments, that you can supply at the time of the call.

I'm not sure if this helps with your problem, but hope it does.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand what your end goal is, so I'm going to suggest you read up a little further on Ruby's object model and methods and provide you some guidance instead.

The `method` method returns an instance of `Method` (an object). If this is confusing, read it more slowly and check out [the Method documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html). Whether the method being referenced by the argument is an instance method or not is irrelevant to the behavior of the `method` method.

Directly addressing something you said in the question: using `method(:foo)` does not call the referenced method (e.g. `foo`).

You *can* unbind a method from the source receiver (creating an [UnboundMethod](https://ruby-doc.org/core/UnboundMethod.html) that can't be called) and rebind it to another receiver if you need to:

```rb
my_method_instance = some_string.method(:to_s)

# Now I can call `some_string.to_s` like so:
my_method_instance.to_s

# This isn't very useful for `to_s`, but it could be in other situations
method_instance = SomeModule::SomeHelper.method(:parse_html)
array_of_html_docs = array_of_strings.map(&method_instance)

# And you can unbind the method from the original receiver:
my_unbound_method_instance = my_method_instance.unbind

# And rebind it elsewhere
my_unbound_method_instance.bind(some_other_receiver)
my_unbound_method_instance.call(args) # receiver is `some_other_receiver` here
```